# Make trusted self-signed certificate not register as "self-signed" (i.e. trusted) on private network

Tags: security, docker, ssl, certificates

I'm currently implementing a [private Docker Registry server with `nginx` configured to forward `https` traffic securely to the running Docker Registry (i.e. `docker-compose`) instance](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-18-04) on a private network (with DNS, DHCP configured).

I have the entire setup working as expected, but had to [create self-signed certificates](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04) as I'm not permitted to use ["Let's Encrypt"](https://letsencrypt.org/) (hard requirement). I've deployed the `.crt` file to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` on all the Ubuntu hosts on my network, and updated the certificate store (i.e. via `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`).

However, even though the certificate is "trusted" (from the step above), the certificate is still registered as "self-signed", and [the only way I can get Docker Registry working fully is by creating a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42211380/add-insecure-registry-to-docker), `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, with the following contents (assuming my Docker Registry instance is running on the `registry` host on my `lan` domain):

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : [ "registry.lan:5000" ]
}
```

This causes some functionality to break (i.e. there are some plugins that won't work if "insecure registries" are enabled).

---

## Question

How can I configure my private network (i.e. assuming it isn't even connected to the internet most of the time) so that all machines on the network "fully trust" the certificate (i.e. so the cert is "publicly trusted" amongst hosts on the local network)? **i.e. what command can I run or config file can I tweak?**

[**This seems like a possible solution: create a CA plus server key on my private network.**](https://gist.github.com/bradrydzewski/a6090115b3fecfc25280)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not enough to add your cert into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`. You have to make sure that it has read chmod for others and also add its relative path into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

Let's say your cert is `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/self-signed/yourcert.crt`

You should edit `/etc/ca-certificates.conf`

```
sudo editor /etc/ca-certificates.conf
```

and add its relative path, relative to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` to be exact.

So it should be something like:

```
self-signed/yourcert.crt
```

Then run

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

You should see 1 certificate added in the above command output.

Keep in mind that this cert will be trusted only on this specific host. You need to also deploy it into your docker containers if you want it to be trusted internaly.